# Rendering of underlined dots in man

Tags: man, roff

If you look at the documentation source for `man(1)` (probably at `/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz`) using, you'll notice lines like this one -

```
.IR page [.\| section \|]\ \|.\|.\|.\|]\ \.\|.\|.\&
```

This gets rendered by man 2.8.3 to

```
page[.section] ...] ... 
----  -------
```

where the `-` denotes underlining. The way I understand this works is that unescaped spaces are stripped, and `IR` alternates between `I` (since italics are unavailable maybe it does underlining) and `R` (which is the normal roman font), and the font gets toggled using `\|`. Based on this, I would expect the rendering to look like -

```
page[.section] ...] ... 
----  -------  - -  ?-
```

Why is that not the case though?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with misunderstanding what the character codes actually do. If you look at the Ossanna and Kernighan's Troff user's manual, you'll see -

```
\|     1/6 em narrow space character (zero width in nroff)
```

So it is not actually alternating the fonts by itself, it only introduces thin spaces. The font alternation is happening because of *spaces* in the text (see [man(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man)) -

```
.IR page [.\| section \|]\ \|.\|.\|.\|]\ \.\|.\|.\&
```

This gets broken up into 4 chunks

```
page
[.\|
section
\|]\ \|.\|.\|.\|]\ \.\|.\|.\&
```

where the fonts alternates between them, giving the rendering that you see, where page and section are underlined, and the other chunks are not.